# Runtime.MalformedHandlerName & BadHandler error AWS CDK

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

My function is just very basic, but calling it gives the same response no matter what i change in the function it self:

```
exports.handler = async function(event) {
  console.log('Success')
  };
```

[image: error]

I am a 100% sure that my stack is correct and the handler and code properties are correct.
CORRECTION: 99%

I also tried debugging, but i did not get much further.

I use NODEJS_16_X as runtime, i tried it with 14 as well but that did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That usually happens when you don't define the `handler` property on the CDK lambda properties:

```
handler: 'handler',
runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_16_X,
timeout: Duration.minutes(15),
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I took a second look at the project, turns out my handler was wrong defined.